# How to load file after being uploaded (not saved in database yet) in angular, html

Tags: html, angular, filereader, angular13

I have a file upload control in my angular app where user could upload any type of file except a few ones .exe, .sql etc

```
    <input type="file" id="file" #file (change)="fileUploadHandler($event)" multiple>
```

fileupload.component.ts

```
fileUploadHandler(event: Event) {
const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
if (inputElement.files && inputElement.files?.length) {
  _each(inputElement.files, (_file) => {
    const fileSize = _file.size;
    if (fileSize < this.MAX_DOC_SIZE) {
      const fileName = _file.name?.trim();
      const doc = new Document();
      doc.name = fileName;
      doc.extension = fileName.slice(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
      doc.size = fileSize;
      this.docs.push(doc);
    } 
  });
}}
```

This list the files in UI  as below

[image]

Now what I need is that when user click on a file, that file should open in a new tab

how can I do this?

On googling I see suggestions to use `FileReader` & gave a try

```
   _each(inputElement.files, (_file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const data = reader.readAsDataURL(_file);
    console.log(data) // nothing is printed on console
```

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: First of all this will not log data, as return type of `readAsDataURL` api is undefined. Please go through this doc, then you'll find your answer. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Answer (score 0):

You have to enhance the code a little bit (as @mav-raj also stated). In Angular you can use the following:

```
_each(inputElement.files, (_file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = ((result) => {
        console.log(result) // now something will be printed!    
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(_file);
})
```